# Psychic medium sin

Tags: exegesis

My question is why is it that going to a medium who gives closure and healing be a sin? The bible says that we were all born with gifts, if they are using their gifts to help people find closure and healing, then is their gifts Not of God??

Comment: You question is to vague. Here would be a catholic response. responsehttps://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/view.cfm?recnum=8755

Comment: Is this my answer??

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/40384/looking-to-mediums-for-closure

Comment: Also, this is possibly a duplicate of http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/26985/what-does-the-bible-say-about-people-who-see-dead-people-on-earth

Answer (score 2):

According to [Deuteronomy 18:10-12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=+Deuteronomy+18%3A10-12&version=NET), [Leviticus 20:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus+20%3A6&version=NIV) and [1 Chronicles 10:13-14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Chronicles+10%3A13-14&version=NIV), these kinds of "gifts" do not come from God.

In [Luke 16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+16%3A19-31&version=NET), Jesus tells a parable about a rich man and a man named Lazarus. In this parable, the rich man dies and goes to hell. From hell, the rich man begins speaking with Abraham, saying,

> "‘Then I beg you, father, send Lazarus to my family, for I have five
>   brothers. Let him warn them, so that they will not also come to this
>   place of torment.’ Abraham replied, ‘They have Moses and the Prophets;
>   let them listen to them.’ ‘No, father Abraham,’ he said, ‘but if
>   someone from the dead goes to them, they will repent.’ He said to him,
>   ‘If they do not listen to Moses and the Prophets, they will not be
>   convinced even if someone rises from the dead.’”

God had a plan for our lives. We were unable to trust in that plan and therefore, [the wage of that sin is death.](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+6%3A23&version=NET). Because we thought our plan was better than God's, we ate from the tree of the [fruit of the knowledge of good and evil.](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+2%3A4-3%3A24&version=NET) We are receiving our due punishment for this. God, being all merciful and loving devised a plan to allow us a second chance by sending his son Jesus.

At it's core, divination and mediums are an assault on that plan. Divination is attempting to see the future and therefore control our destiny. As Christians, we should putting our trust in God for our future. [In Matthew 6:25-34 Jesus says,](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+6%3A25-34&version=NET)

> Therefore I tell you, do not worry about your life, what you will eat
>   or drink, or about your body, what you will wear. Isn’t there more to
>   life than food and more to the body than clothing? Look at the birds
>   in the sky: They do not sow, or reap, or gather into barns, yet your
>   heavenly Father feeds them. Aren’t you more valuable than they are?
>   And which of you by worrying can add even one hour to his life? Why do
>   you worry about clothing? Think about how the flowers of the field
>   grow; they do not work or spin. Yet I tell you that not even Solomon
>   in all his glory was clothed like one of these! And if this is how God
>   clothes the wild grass, which is here today and tomorrow is tossed
>   into the fire to heat the oven, won’t he clothe you even more, you
>   people of little faith? So then, don’t worry saying, ‘What will we
>   eat?’ or ‘What will we drink?’ or ‘What will we wear?’ For the
>   unconverted pursue these things, and your heavenly Father knows that
>   you need them. But above all pursue his kingdom and righteousness, and
>   all these things will be given to you as well. So then, do not worry
>   about tomorrow, for tomorrow will worry about itself. Today has enough
>   trouble of its own.

In short, it is we who caused death and while it is always hard to lose a loved one, when we make bad choices, there are consequences to our actions that we must live with. This is one of them. By attempting to avoid those consequences, we are attempting to usurp God. Christians instead should be seeking comfort and closure in the one who defeated death and will resurrect us all (Jesus) and not in psychic mediums. When we consult psychics and mediums, we fail to do that and are sinning yet again. This is not to say that it is not OK to mourn the loss of a loved one. [Even Jesus mourned the loss of his friend.](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+11%3A33-36&version=NET)

Finally, you should also be concerned that you may not be talking to the spirit you think you are talking to. (For, example, see the story of the [slave girl in phillipi](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%2016:16-18&version=NET)) It is possible that you are talking to a malevolent entity which is attmepting to mislead you. By following pagans by consulting psychics and mediums, (something which is repeatedly stated as not being of God) and by drawing you away from putting your faith in God, any such evil spirit successfully draws you away from God. It would be wise to be cautious by avoiding this altogether.